# How to log all the commands being executed by all Unix users in a file?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface

I am able to monitor all the commands by all users at a interval of 5 seconds or so

```
$watch -n5 w
```

This shows me the commands run by all the Unix users in the putty how do i log all the commands on new lines in a text file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just want to keep a track history of what commands my unix users are executing on their terminals

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `w` in a loop and sleep 5 seconds after every execution. Then pipe the results to a file:

```
while true; do w ; sleep 5; done > file
```

Ideally you'll run that in background, started by an init script at boot time.

I've just explained that from the shell coding perspective. The solution itself is not very stable since it will miss commands which run less than 5 seconds and being executed between two invocations of `w`.

Comment: Thanks much for the help! 
Is there any turnaround to log all commands and not just the ones after every 5 seconds?

Comment: Not something that comes out of the box, at least I'm not aware of such a thing. Make sure that permissions are set properly so that users can execute commands like they wish but will not harm the system.